# Do field skills stack with multiple blades?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Do field skills stack if I have multiple blades with the same ability? For example, if I come across a chest that requires level 3 focus to open, can I equip one blade with level 2 focus and another with level 1 focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, yes.

> If you just need a higher level for field skills, remember that field skills stack from different blades.

According to [Aminoapp](https://aminoapps.com/c/xenoblade/page/blog/increasing-field-skills-xenoblade-chronicles-2/wmlX_qmcouBNLlN3L8RMQ1jxXZj1dxo0EY).

Comment: After playing the snot out of XB2, I can confirm this is correct. In fact there are many field skill locations that *require* them to be stacked